# Truncate all values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the first column being dates and then lots of adjusted stock prices (some of which have 16 decimals). I would like to truncate all the dataframe values to 8 decimals so I tried the following:

```
df = df.set_index("Day").pipe(lambda x: math.trunc(100000000 * x) / 100000000).reset_index()
```

But I get the following error:

```
type DataFrame doesn't define __trunc__ method
```

Comment: use `applymap` instead of `apply` or `pipe` for applying your function (which expects an integer) on each cell, instead of each row. Check my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.trunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trunc.html) for a vectorial solution:

```
n = 10**8
out = np.trunc(df.set_index("Day").mul(n)).div(n).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, **you are trying to apply the truncate-based lambda function on multiple columns at once**. That's the reason for the error, try using `applymap` which applies your function on each cell independently. You have to first set your date column as index, leaving only the float columns in the dataframe. Try this -

```
f = lambda x: math.trunc(100000000 * x) / 100000000  #<-- your function
df.set_index("Day").applymap(f).reset_index()        #<-- applied on each cell
```

---

Since I don't have the sample dataset you are using, here is a working dummy example.

```
import math
import pandas as pd

#Dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,3)), 
                  columns = ['col1','col2','col3'])

f = lambda x: math.trunc(100 * x) / 100
df.applymap(f)
```

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  0.80  0.76  0.14
1  0.40  0.48  0.85
2  0.58  0.40  0.76
3  0.82  0.04  0.10
4  0.23  0.04  0.91
5  0.57  0.41  0.12
6  0.72  0.71  0.71
7  0.32  0.59  0.99
8  0.11  0.70  0.32
9  0.95  0.80  0.24
```

---

Another simpler solution is to just use `df.set_index("Day").round(8)` directly, if that works for you but that would be rounding your numbers to 8 digits instead of truncating.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried formatting?

```py
dec = [1.2736,9.3745,5.412783,8.25389]
to_3dp = lambda x: '%.3f'%(x)
rounded = [to_3dp(i) for i in dec]
print(rounded) # [1.273, 9.374, 5.412, 8.253]
```

So in your case:

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: '%.8f'%(x))
```

If you want to round:

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda x: round(x,8))
```

Comment: Truncating isn't the same as rounding if i am not mistaken.

Comment: Is it where you don't round but just get the first `n` digits

Comment: Yes, but rounding gives a better approximation.

Comment: Is it better now? (code)

Comment: @nonlinear, that's debatable and depends on the end goal

Comment: Yes! But i don't really understand why he needs to truncate and not round.

Comment: What about I just do rounding **and** truncating?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I need to truncate because I am trying to replicate a calculation that was given to me with no explanation, and I recently found that they do not use all decimals, so I had to truncate.